# C++ Template Swap Function

Tags: c++, templates, reference, pass-by-reference, swap

I need to make a swap function that swaps two parameters of type T.

And following is what I code but something must be wrong.

Could anybody better my codes?

```
template<typename T>
void swap (T& a, T& b)
{ T temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

Should I pass it as constant reference? But I am changing the values right?

Please let me know thanks!!

Comment: It's fine the way it is, though you should use `std::swap` by the way.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? As far as I can see it looks correct.

Comment: If you pass by const-reference it can't be modified and the compiler will punish you.

Comment: try writing template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compiler supports it, you should pass your parameters through an rvalue-reference and use `std::move` to convert to rvalues:

```
template <class T>
void swap(T&&, T&&);

int main()
{
    int n(0);

    swap(std::move(n), 5); // n is now 5
}
```

In your code this would not have been possible because lvalues cannot bind to rvalues. But with this little feature disregarded your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you might be having is the naming of your swap function. Try naming it mySwap, instead. I had the same problem once. The swap function is predefined in c++;

Answer (score -2):

Use the standard swap as provided by the STL.